# spaCy: collapsed dependencies

Tags: stanford-nlp, spacy

Is there a way to get collapsed dependencies from the parser using spacy? I mean the Stanford definition of CSD viz.

> In the collapsed representation, dependencies involving prepositions,
>   conjuncts, as well as information about the referent of relative
>   clauses are collapsed to get direct dependencies between content words

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There has been a [discussion](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/60) on this issue in Spacy's github page. It seems the current API doesn't provide this.

You can probably use a constituency parser along with the dependency parse and write rules to get the collapsed dependencies.

Comment: thanks 0x5050. Is there a documented logic of the collapsing dependencies? Like merging the prep etc. I have seen some of the examples and think I would be able to write the rules if a comprehensive list of all conditions is available. Would you know of the availability of any such documentation of rules? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[JoBimText Dependency Collasping](http://ltmaggie.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/jobimtext/components/dependency-collapsing/) may do what you want.

You can use it to produced collapsed dependencies from raw text:

`java -jar org.jobimtext.collapsing.jar -i corpus/en -o output -f t`

Or you can give it CoNLL input (where tagging/parsing have already been applied) and it will collapse the dependencies for you:

`java -jar org.jobimtext.collapsing.jar -i corpus_tagged -o output -f c -np -nt`

If you just want to understand their process for collapsing the dependencies, see the technical report in [this repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/jobimtext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/org.jobimtext.collapsing/resources/).